# Replace part of a string in XML using XSL

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, replace

I have the following xml:

```
<links url="../servlet/SearchServlet?query=contact&filter=&sort=relevance&sortdir=desc&col=5&startdate=0&enddate=0&xsl=xml&page=">

<link page="date" url="../servlet/SearchServlet?query=contact&filter=&sort=date&col=5&startdate=0&enddate=0&page=1&xsl=xml"/>
```

I am using this xsl to transform the links:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//link">

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@page='next'">
                    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                    <a href="{@url}">&gt;&gt;</a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@page='prev'">
                    <a href="{@url}">&lt;&lt;</a>
                    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="@page='date'"/>
                <xsl:when test="@page='relevance'"/>
                <xsl:when test="@page='alpha'"/>

            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

The tricky part now is I want to replace part of the `url` in the link from `../servlet/SearchServlet` to `../search`

How do I achieve this? I tried [using this template](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) but it replaces the whole `url`.

Comment: Please show how you tried to use the linked template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="link/@url">
  <xsl:param name="search"  select="'../servlet/SearchServlet'" />
  <xsl:param name="replace" select="'../search'" />
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(., $search)">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($replace, substring-after(., $search))" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

call as

```
<a>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@url" />
  <xsl:text>&lt;&lt;</xsl:text>
</a>
```

Note that you could optionally use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@url" />
  <xsl:with-param name="search"  select="'xyz'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'foo'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

to supply different search/replace values.

Comment: Tomalak, you might be interested to see a simler and shorter solution :)

Comment: @Dimitre I was aiming for a generic variant. But yes, AVTs are nicer for the specific case.

Comment: Tomalak, In what sense is your solution more generic than mine?

Comment: @Dimitre Well, you could argue that it is push-style and therefore more modular and re-usable, plus it allows different replacements via template parameters.

Comment: Tomalak: Which solution isn't push style? Which is more modular/reusable? Which doesn't allow different replacements via parameters? I am confused.

Comment: @Dimitre I give up. This is not really more generic than your solution.

Comment: Tomalak: Fully agreed. I think this was obvious from the start, but I am glad that you also were able to arrive to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a simpler and shorter, complete solution, not using any explicit conditional instructions or `xsl:attribute`:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pTarget" select="'../servlet/SearchServlet'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pRep" select="'../search'"/>

 <xsl:template match="link">
  <xsl:variable name="vCUrl" select="concat(@url, $pTarget)"/>

  <a url="{substring-before($vCUrl,$pTarget)}{$pRep}{substring-after(@url,$pTarget)}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@page"/>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link/@page[. = 'next']">>></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="link/@page[. = 'prev']">&lt;&lt;</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link[not(@page='next' or @page='prev')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<links>
 <link page="prev" url="../servlet/SearchServlet?query=contact&amp;filter=&amp;sort=relevance&amp;sortdir=desc&amp;col=5&amp;startdate=0&amp;enddate=0&amp;xsl=xml&amp;page="/>
 <link page="date" url="../servlet/SearchServlet?query=contact&amp;filter=&amp;sort=date&amp;col=5&amp;startdate=0&amp;enddate=0&amp;page=1&amp;xsl=xml"/>
 <link page="next" url="../servlet/SearchServlet?query=contact&amp;filter=&amp;sort=date&amp;col=5&amp;startdate=0&amp;enddate=0&amp;page=1&amp;xsl=xml"/>
</links>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<a url="../search?query=contact&amp;filter=&amp;sort=relevance&amp;sortdir=desc&amp;col=5&amp;startdate=0&amp;enddate=0&amp;xsl=xml&amp;page=">&lt;&lt;</a>
<a url="../search?query=contact&amp;filter=&amp;sort=date&amp;col=5&amp;startdate=0&amp;enddate=0&amp;page=1&amp;xsl=xml">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Appropriate use of AVT (**[Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)**)
2. Appropriate use of pattern matching and templates.
3. Adding a sentinel to a string so that conditional processing becomes unnecessary.