# Formatting XSLT document

Tags: xml, xslt, text

I have an XSLT file for transforming data from table to INSERT statements.
So the output looks like

```
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (Voda, Šenov);

INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (Vorba, Vlčnov);
```

which is fine to me.
My XSLT contains this three lines

```
<xsl:for-each select="PAGE/ROWSET/ROW">
  INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (<xsl:value-of select="SURNAME"/>, <xsl:value-of select="CITY"/>);
</xsl:for-each>
```

And here is the question, I really dont want to put so many values on the same line(my table has like 20 columns) in order to maintain the formatting in output, so is there a way how to keep output the same and have my columns in INSERT on multiple lines in `for-each`?

Thanks a lot for answers

**EDIT**

I would like to have the `for-each` loop like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="PAGE/ROWSET/ROW">
  INSERT INTO some_table VALUES va1 ,val2 (
         <xsl:value-of select="SURNAME"/>, 
         <xsl:value-of select="CITY"/>);
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Why do you need to put them on the same line? Is there a reason that you cannot put the parameters on different lines?

Comment: See my edit. Thing is that I will do some debugging on this code so I would like to have it nicely formatted:-)

Comment: If you were to use an XML editor with 'virtual formatting' (auto-indents without tabs/spaces) then line-length would be a non-issue, because your XML would always wrap properly to the editor margins and yet still be properly indented. Of course, issues will arise if you then switch to a conventional 'padded-formatting' editor later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="PAGE/ROWSET/ROW">
            <xsl:text>INSERT INTO some_table VALUES val1 ,val2 (</xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="SURNAME"/><xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                 <xsl:value-of select="CITY"/><xsl:text>);</xsl:text>
                 <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XML Spy, with input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PAGE>
    <ROWSET>
        <ROW>
            <SURNAME>sn1</SURNAME>
            <CITY>c1</CITY>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <SURNAME>sn2</SURNAME>
            <CITY>c2</CITY>
        </ROW>
    </ROWSET>
</PAGE>
```

I get

```
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES val1 ,val2 (sn1, c1);
INSERT INTO some_table VALUES val1 ,val2 (sn2, c2);
```

Comment: +1. Note that the values must be wrapped in single quotes at least. To be safer against SQL injection (and broken code) single quotes in the values themselves must be escaped, which would require a string replace function [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8971550/18771).